# Trigger scan through netsh on win7

Tags: netsh

I used the following command to trigger scan on WiFi `interface netsh wlan show networks`. However I found that this command return Windows 7 scan result without sending them to the relevant WiFi driver.

Is there any command I should use to trigger scan to WiFi driver? Thanks